# Remove rows with conduit-csv

Tags: csv, haskell, conduit

trying to consume a csv file and remove the first 4 rows then continue with my parsing:

```
parsePowerCsv
  :: MonadThrow m
  => ConduitT () ByteString m () -> m [PowerFields]
parsePowerCsv bs = do
  runConduit $
       bs
      .| CL.consume
      .| (dropC 4 >> intoCSV defCSVSettings)
```

So I'm able to produce a list of `Text` but want to be able to convert to my `PowerFields` type easily since I have `From/To NamedRecord` instances but I want to remove those first 4 rows.

so after `dropC` I am not able to parse the `[Text]`to the  `[PowerFields]`

```
data PowerFields =
  PowerFields
    { VA_avg         :: Maybe Double
    , A_avg          :: Maybe Double
    , Wh_sum         :: Maybe Double
    ...
    } deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

Comment: The question could be somewhat improved cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You mention dropping 4 rows or 4 columns, which is it? `intoCSV` should do the hard work of constructing your custom type, you just need to unwrap it with `getNamed`.

Comment: sorry 4 "rows"!! csv taken over my brain

Answer (score 0):

Because `intoCSV` expects to stream in the whole file, rather than read a stream of lines, you'll want to use a conduit that can parse and drop lines directly from an input bytestring stream, rather than trying to work with a list of lines.

Something like the following should work:

```
parsePowerCsv bs = do
  runConduit $
      bs
      .| (replicateM_ 4 (lineAsciiC sinkNull) >>
          intoCSV defCSVSettings)
      .| sinkList -- (dropC 4 >> sinkList)
```